# Inserting data into separate tables quickly and reliably

Tags: mysql, performance, insert

Let's say we get the following data from a CSV file:

```
account_number balance customer name
100            500.00  GERN BLANSTON
101            800.00  GERN BLANSTON
102            200.00  OPRAH WINFREY
```

This represents two accounts belonging to Gern Blanston and one belonging to Oprah Winfrey. Now let's say we have a `customer` table and an `account` table. We could hypothetically insert the data using just two `INSERT` statements:

```
INSERT INTO customer
  (name)
VALUES
  ('GERN BLANSTON'),
  ('OPRAH WINFREY')
```

and

```
INSERT INTO account
  (account_number, balance, customer_id)
VALUES
  (100, 500.00, ???),
  (101, 800.00, ???),
  (102, 200.00, ???)
```

If we knew the IDs for Gern Blanston and Oprah Winfrey, we could of course use those IDs in the second `INSERT` statement and it would work fine. But one way or another, we need to get those IDs.

My question: is there a fast way to find out, or at least keep track of, the IDs of each inserted customer? Inserting each row individually and then getting `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is too slow for me (I have up to 65,000 accounts in each CSV file). Looking up the customer ID each time I insert a new account is also too slow.

Or, if you want to sidestep that particular question and recommend a different solution, I'm open to that as well. I'm using MySQL.

Comment: +1 for the Steve Martin reference. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add another column for table `account`, which store `customer_name`, after complete the insertion, just `update account set customer_id=(select customer.customer_id from customer where customer.customer_name=account.customer_name;`

hope this alternative workaround simplify the complexity

also, change your `customer table` to have auto_increment for `customer_id`

Comment: I believe the table already have an auto_increment on `customer_id`, since the OP specifies the column name in the insert into `customer` table.

Comment: @Danosaure - i cannot assume that without the full table schema, is good for everyone post along their table schema, dun make the answerer begging

Comment: Only saying because he did mention about the `last_insert_id()`

Comment: I thought of doing this when I was pondering this earlier. I'm not crazy about it because it involves some de-normalization, but maybe that's the sacrifice I have to make for performance.

Comment: @Jason Swett, u dun have to, just drop the column after u update :-)